# JOIN a table for 2 fields

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables, which I need to gather information from for 2 fields

```
Table A
- ID
- WorkerResponsible
- WorkerTaker

Table B
- Id
- Name
- PersonnelNumber
```

I want to display the PersonnelNumber (MV) instead of the ID, but I am also not sure how to JOIN because of the 2 field, I have tried the following select code, but I am not sure if I have to join 2 times.

How can I gather the right information for both fields?

```
SELECT
TableA.WorkerResponsible AS WorkerResponsible,
TableA.WorkerTaker AS WorkerTaker,
TableB.PersonnelNumber AS WorkerSalesResponsibleCode,
TableB.PersonnelNumber AS WorkerSalesTakerCode

FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableB.Id = TableA.WorkerSalesResponsible AND TableB.Id = TableA.WorkerSalesTaker
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should join the tableB two times using alias  (this way)

```
SELECT
TableA.WorkerResponsible AS WorkerResponsible,
TableA.WorkerTaker AS WorkerTaker,
tb1.PersonnelNumber AS WorkerSalesResponsibleCode,
tb2.PersonnelNumber AS WorkerSalesTakerCode

FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB as tb1 ON tb1.Id = TableA.WorkerSalesResponsible 
INNER JOIN TableB as tb2 ON tb2.Id = TableA.WorkerSalesTaker
```

Comment: I think its problem solving answer.